# AngularJS ng-repeat ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to have a grid of images, when clicked the image is hid from the grid and shown featured at the top.

HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="imageCtrl">
      <div class="row">
        <img ng-show="selected" src="{{selected.img}}" alt="">
        <p ng-show="selected">{{selected.des}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="(id, image) in images" class="col-sm-4">
          <a ng-click="clicked(id)"><img src="{{image.img}}" alt=""></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And my controller:

```
light.controller('imageCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.images = [{img: '',des: ''},{img: '',des: ''},{img: '',des: ''}];
  $scope.selected = $scope.images[0];
  $scope.clicked = function(id){
    selected = $scope.images[id];
};
```

});

Currently the first image is shown but when I click on other images nothing happens. Anybody have any tips as to what I'm doing wrong? Thank You!

Comment: I don't think you can use `(x,y) in z` syntax in `ng-repeat` - instead just use `ng-repeat="image in images"` and then use the `$index` variable, which is available inside an `ng-repeat`, as the replacement for your current `id`.

Comment: Do I use $index in ng-click="clicked($index)" or is it used in my function?

Comment: Use `clicked($index)` and in your function you can keep `id` as is.

Comment: But, @nilsK's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

you'll need to set `$scope.selected` not `selected`

```
$scope.clicked = function(id){
   $scope.selected = $scope.images[id];
}
```

EDIT: i suck at plunker ;)

anyways: use ng-repeat as you did in your first example and it should work

```
<div ng-repeat="(id, image) in images" class="col-sm-4">
   <a ng-click="clicked(id)"><img src="{{image.img}}" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Still no luck any other thoughts? I'm stumped.

Comment: Pretty sure. Check it out https://lightboxtest.myshopify.com/ click on the image of Richard Sherman

Comment: I just don't think my click is being registerd

Comment: @user3621884 switch back to your first ng-repeat expression. i edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In html, instead of passing id pass the index value as

ng-click="clicked($index)"

In the controller,

```
$scope.clicked = function(Index){
$scope.selected = $scope.images[Index];
```

};

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead:

```
<img ng-show="selected" ng-src="{{selected.img}}" alt="">
```

Use ng-src={{selected.image}} in your image tag instead of just src={{selected.image}}.  Angular will know it needs to update the image if the model its pointing to has been updated

Comment: Any thoughts ExpertSys?

Comment: Sorry that didn't work, @ExpertSystem I don't know how that could be considered unrelated as that could produce the exact symptoms.  Can you verify that the contents of selected are being updated on click?

Comment: @TyndieRock: `src="{{...}}"` will work fine as sson as Angular kicks in and replaces the template. So, it could not produce the symptoms.

Comment: I don't think they are. Is their anyway to check for certain?

Comment: This is definitely not the issue.